# Munkres Chapter 1 Section 7 Exercise 6 (a)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $B \subset A$ and there is an injective function $f \colon A \to B$, then the sets $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality.

Here's the hint provided by Munkres:

Define $A_1 \colon= A$, $B_1 \colon= B$, and for $n > 1$, define $A_n \colon= f(A_{n-1})$, and $B_n \colon= f(B_{n-1})$. Note that $A_1 \supset B_1 \supset A_2 \supset B_2 \supset A_3 \supset \cdots$. Define a bijection $h \colon A \to B$ by the rule $$h(x) \colon= \begin{cases} f(x) \mbox{ if } x \in A_n - B_n \mbox{ for some } n; \\ x \mbox{ otherwise }. \end{cases} $$

Now my question is, how to show that the map $h$ is actually a bijection?

In particular, if $x$, $y$ $\in A$ such that $h(x) = h(y)$, $x \in A_n - B_n$ for some $n$, $y \not\in A_n - B_n$ for any $n$, then how to show that $x = y$ in order to show that $h$ is injective?

And, how to show that $h$ is surjective?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem

Comment: @Asaf, this link doesn't provide the proof I'm requiring.

Comment: I didn't give you any link. I've edited the post. Try pinging someone else. :-)

Comment: @Mirko Swirko the link you've given doesn't give my required proof.